# lubuntu - math library in code::blocks - sqrt()

Tags: lubuntu, compiling

I have recently installed Lubuntu (not sure which one - the last LTS) with LXQT 0.14.1. I'm using code::blocks to code in c.
When I wrote sqrt(15), everything was ok. But when I wrote sqrt(a) (a is a double), the compiler gave me an error - "undefined reference to 'sqrt'".
Someone told me to go to Project--> Build options --> Linker setting
and to add libm.so. But when I did this, I got a new error: "cannot find -lm.so"

How can I solve this?

Comment: I don't really know anything about code::blocks, but I would expect the correct linker option on a Linux system to be `-lm` rather than `libm.so`

Comment: Its' the first thing I did, but it didn't work. I got the same message. But thanks!

Comment: I'd check what you actually installed, as the *latest* or *last* LTS released contained LXQt 0.17 (refer https://lubuntu.me/jammy-released/) but could be upgraded to LXQt 1.1 using the [Lubuntu backports PPA](https://lubuntu.me/jammy-backports-22-04-1/).   My guess is you installed 20.04, the version that whilst is still supported, no longer has a manual available in published form (*22.04 is now the LTS manual*)  being in its last months of supported life.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was easier than I thought. I simply changed the libm.so to libm, and it solved the problem.